# Как правильно написать php код в атрибут id HTML кнопки?

Tags: php, html5

```
<button id="<?php echo $row[ProdCan_ID];?>" class="btn" type="submit">Добавить</button>
```

Такой вариант просто не хочет работать...
Проблема вот в чем, данный php код по идее должен отрабатывать И! внимание! когда я смотрю на элементы страницы (chrome) то в id я должен видеть значение переменной т.е. `id="1"`. Я же вижу `id="<?php echo $row[ProdCan_ID];?>"`...... Это говорит о том что он не отрабатывает.

Comment: и как не хочет - какие ошибКИ?

Comment: Может завернуть индекс элемента массива в кавычки? $row['ProdCan_ID']

Comment: так не работает, все начинает ругаться и не может определить переменную

Comment: ^ Это надо в вопросе писать, а не в комментариях. Вот ссылка [edit].

Comment: варианты с кавычками я перепробовал кучу, ничего не помогает... Такой вариант как есть без ошибок, но он не живой(((

Comment: @Skydiver19 вы учли комментарий frozencoast ?

Comment: Вы бы привели больший фрагмент кода, может вы неверно указали название элемента массива, а может и самого массива, причин может быть множество, чем больше вы предоставите деталей, тем уже будет список возможных причин

Comment: "все начинает ругаться" - это вообще не разговор. Когда просите помощи, давайте конкретные сведения. Наверное "ругается" - значит вы получаете какие-то ошибки. Какие именно? (их нужно писать в тексте вопроса).

Comment: Срабатывает ли другой РНР код на странице? Банально переспрошу, а файл с расширением рнр или html?

Comment: опубликуйте текст вашей ошибки. без этого не понятно о чем речь идет. Возможно у вас файл с html расширением вместо php.

Answer (score 0):

я обычно пишу так

```
<button id="<?=$row['ProdCan_ID'];?>" class="btn" type="submit">Добавить</button>
```

да, главное чтобы расширение файла в котором находится данный код было .php